# nav bar alignment tailwind left and right not equal

Tags: css, tailwind-css

here is an image of the navbar
[image]

here is my code:

```
<nav class="Vdark-2 shadow-xl">
  <div class="container mx-28 ">
    <div class="relative flex items-center h-16 justify-between">
      <div class="Vwhite-text text-4xl ml-10 myfont text-left">The Name of my website</div>

      <div class="text-right">
        <span class="Vwhite-text text-xl myfont mx-10">Home</span>
        <span class="Vwhite-text text-xl myfont mx-10">________</span>
        <span class="Vwhite-text text-xl myfont ml-10">______</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

the question to me is, why is this unequal on the sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your margin have a value fixed so your container does not auto center

Changing `<div class="container mx-28 ">` to `<div class="container mx-auto">`

should do the trick